# In AIML How To Use Wildcard Without Space

Tags: chatbot, aiml

In Aiml I'm trying to detect random nonsense words but why is it not working? Here is the code

```
<category> 
<pattern>* f g h *</pattern> 
<template>What nonsense did you just typed??</template>
</category>
```

The response is

```
Human: hdhfghjrur
Robot: pattern did not matched
```

How do you use wildcards without giving space

Why is fgh not matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcards match whole words, not just strings of letters but you can add an entry in your normal substitution file for each nonsense string you want to catch.

```
["fgh", " BadInput "],
```

This will convert your sample input of `hdhfghjrur` to `hdh BadInput jrur` and then you can create a category to deal with this:

```
<category>
    <pattern># BadInput ^</pattern>
    <template>What nonsense did you just type??</template>
</category>
```